# How to publish nuget packages from AppVeyor CI to Azure DevOps artifacts

Tags: continuous-integration, azure-devops, nuget, appveyor

I tried looking into it but couldn't find a documentation page at all. We have an AppVeyor CI build that we produce nuget packages from (here we run our own powershell script), and we want to publish those to a private Azure DevOps artifacts.

I can't seem to get authentication to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How to publish nuget packages from AppVeyor CI to Azure DevOps artifacts

Yes, you are right. You are trying to cross-platform work, but it seems that we are currently unable to complete the certification of Azure DevOps artifacts from AppVeyor CI.

To resolve this issue, you could try to create your private feed for your organization via AppVeyor or publish nuget packages with Azure DevOps build pipeline.

Check [A private feed for your organization via AppVeyor](https://www.petermorlion.com/a-private-feed-for-your-organization-via-appveyor/) and [NuGet Package Management in VSTS](https://www.dotnetcurry.com/visualstudio/1408/nuget-package-management-vsts) for some more details.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thank you, at least my suspicions are confirmed. Unfortunately I just can't use an AppVeyor configured feed as we still need a stable-like feed for real releases. At this rate we might need to use Azure DevOps' build pipeline just to do this.